# How to retrieve data of user from firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a profile page but I am not able to retrieve user details stored under users as a root node. And each user is stored under its userid node, but I only retrieving profile picture of user and rest of details are not retrieved-

**Here is my code for DisplayProfile.java**

```
public class DisplayProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "DisplayProfile";
public static final String Firebase_Server_URL = "https://gakusei-go.firebaseio.com/";


private ImageView profilePic;
private TextView profileName, profilePhone, profileEmail;
private Button profileUpdate;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
private String userID;
FirebaseUser user;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_profile);

    profileUpdate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pbuttonSave);
    profilePic = findViewById(R.id.ivProfilePic);
    profileName = findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName);
    profilePhone = findViewById(R.id.tvProfilePhone);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    System.out.println(userID);
    firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    userID = firebaseAuth.getUid();
    System.out.println(userID);
    profileUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(DisplayProfile.this, SecondActivity.class));

        }

    })
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
       @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully signed in with: " + user.getEmail());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!" +user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                                  Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfuly signed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
    StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference();
    storageReference.child("images").child(firebaseAuth.getUid()+ "." + "jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            Picasso.get().load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(profilePic);
        }
    });
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot Mainsnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot datasnapShot : Mainsnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Users userProfile = datasnapShot.getValue(Users.class);
                profileName.setText("Name: " + userProfile.getName());
                profilePhone.setText("Age: " + userProfile.getPhone());
                profileEmail.setText("Email: " + userProfile.getEmail());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(DisplayProfile.this, databaseError.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
  }
 }
```

**The code for Users.java is here**

```
    package com.example.deepak.myapplication;


   public class Users {
   public String imageUrl;
   public String imageName;
   public String uid;
   public String name;
   public String email;
   public String password;
   public String phone;

public Users() {
}


public Users(String uid, String name, String email, String password, String phone) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
```

}

**My Display_activity is here**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_image_upload"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivProfilePic"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.238"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pbuttonSave"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="140dp"
    android:text="Edit"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvProfilePhone" />


<TextView

    android:id="@+id/tvProfileName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="208dp"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.401"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivProfilePic" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvProfilePhone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Phone: "
    android:textSize="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.378"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvProfileName"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.391" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvProfileEmail"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
    android:text="Email"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.384"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is **my database structure**

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbmfr.png)

Comment: post database structure.

Comment: Also please just put the code in which you're trying to retrieve from Firebase Database, posting the whole code which is not needed, makes the question harder to read.

Comment: Added link to my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your database you have:

```
 users
     userId 
         name : user_name
         phone : user_phone
```

Then you need to do the following:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
```

In your code you have `getReference("user")` and then you wrote `child("users")` which means you are accessing a node that doesnt exist in your  database.

---

Full code:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot mainSnapshot) {

            Users userProfile = mainSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
            profileName.setText("Name: " + userProfile.getName());
            profilePhone.setText("Phone: " + userProfile.getPhone());
            profileEmail.setText("Email: " + userProfile.getEmail());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Copy thr code exactly as i wrote here in the edit, you have other mistakes also..

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.deepak.myapplication.DisplayProfile$4.onDataChange(DisplayProfile.java:132)

Comment: Look at your code, you didnt initialiaze profileEmail thats why you get null point exception..

Comment: Do this `profileEmail = findViewById(R.id.ivProfileEmail);` the id should be the one in the xml

Comment: two days ago everything was working fine but today null pointer exception occur at 'java.lang.String com.example.deepak.myapplication.Users.getName()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.deepak.myapplication.DisplayProfile$5.onDataChange(DisplayProfile.java:144)

Comment: yes here is what I did  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737276/not-able-to-update-data-of-user-on-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the `getReference("user")` and then further referencing the child `users`

But you still manage to get the profile image because you're fetching the image with direct reference to cloud storage where you already know that the profile picture is named `gs://<bucket>/images/<uid>.jpg` (not using the the `imageURL` value that you're having in the users data in RTDB)

Comment: Then can you help me how to get user details after changing that reference. Because even after changing references as mentioned solution above by someone still not getting any details

Comment: Can you post your database rules? (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

Comment: everything is defined as public as you can the image of database where it is mentioned your database rules are defined public

Comment: It might be because you changed the line `.child("users")` into `.child("userID")`. Work slower with your code and contemplate the changes and wha tthey mean.

Comment: Then can you suggest me how should I proceed further?

Comment: I suggested an edit for your question. Get your reference like this: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userID)`

Comment: Still not woking